# How to access a DB2 database(Z OS) from an IBM I Midrange server?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, mainframe, db2-400

We are currently in an IBM I series server with RPGLE, Cobol, CL programs with the Midrange DB2 and would like to reach out to the database hosted in IBM Z - Mainframe within the same organisation - What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: It will be different depending on which language your program is in. There is no single answer.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve and which OS releases you're running. There is no "best way" vs. "Reach out". Also, please describe what you did so far and where you failed. This site is not a HowTo-Generator but people who opt to help with precise instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define the DB2 for ZOS database in `WRKRDBDIRE`. Once you have the database defined, you can use a `CONNECT` statement in SQL to make the connection, and then do standard SQL to access it.